# Unable to connect to production db for taking custom pg_dump

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying a `pg_dump` on production db using `heroku pg:credentials`. When I try to take dump, it takes a long time and gives me this error:

> SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out

However, connecting to the db using the same credentials using `psql` command works fine.

I tried

```
pg_dump -s -h abcded.compute.amazonaws.com -d adflaksjdfl23 -U username -p 5512
Password:
```

Result:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT c.tableoid, c.oid, c.relname, c.relacl, c.relkind, c.relnamespace, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = c.relowner) AS rolname, c.relchecks, c.relhastriggers, c.relhasindex, c.relhasrules, c.relhasoids, c.relfrozenxid, c.relminmxid, tc.oid AS toid, tc.relfrozenxid AS tfrozenxid, tc.relminmxid AS tminmxid, c.relpersistence, c.relispopulated, 'd' AS relreplident, c.relpages, CASE WHEN c.reloftype <> 0 THEN c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype ELSE NULL END AS reloftype, d.refobjid AS owning_tab, d.refobjsubid AS owning_col, (SELECT spcname FROM pg_tablespace t WHERE t.oid = c.reltablespace) AS reltablespace, array_to_string(array_remove(array_remove(c.reloptions,'check_option=local'),'check_option=cascaded'), ', ') AS reloptions, CASE WHEN 'check_option=local' = ANY (c.reloptions) THEN 'LOCAL'::text WHEN 'check_option=cascaded' = ANY (c.reloptions) THEN 'CASCADED'::text ELSE NULL END AS checkoption, array_to_string(array(SELECT 'toast.' || x FROM unnest(tc.reloptions) x), ', ') AS toast_reloptions FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_depend d ON (c.relkind = 'S' AND d.classid = c.tableoid AND d.objid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0 AND d.refclassid = c.tableoid AND d.deptype = 'a') LEFT JOIN pg_class tc ON (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid) WHERE c.relkind in ('r', 'S', 'v', 'c', 'm', 'f') ORDER BY c.oid
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's failing for you, but if it works you can use Heroku toolbelt to capture the dump and download it.

This can be done in two simple steps:

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app app-name
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app-name`
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export

Comment: I need to use pg_dump and cannot use heroku pg:backups because I need to pass custom pg_dump options which are not possible with heroku command.

Comment: what if you get the dump inside your local database and then use `pg_dump` on it ?